# Android Styling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an image which is inside a linear layout. The size of the image is small so that it does not cover the whole screen. I want the image to be placed in the center of the screen. I used the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll4"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="exitApplication"
        android:contentDescription="exit"           
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/exitbutton" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem I am facing is that if I click anywhere horizontally on the sides of the image, the `onClick` function gets called. How can this I solve this problem?

Comment: well your image spans the entire width of the screen so of course onClick is going to get called

Comment: Place the image in a `RelativeLayout` instead and make width and height both `wrap_content`. You can then let the layout center the image.

Comment: tyczj ,i also know the reason why that bug is coming

Comment: 323- your solution also didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make width of `imageView` as `wrapcontent` and give `gravity` to `linearLayout`

Try following data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="exit"
         android:onClick="exitApplication"
        android:src="@drawable/dolphin1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your image takes the whole width of the screen. To fix it you have to use this for your `ImageView`:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

And use a `RelativeLayout` as main layout.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem, as image was not coming in the center

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

**The `LinearLayout`**:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

A layout should (regularly) fill the screen. That's why we set the `layout_height` and `layout_width` properties to `match_parent`.

**The `ImageView`**:

```
<ImageView>
    ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
</ImageView>
```

The `ImageView` should have an specific width size or be set to `wrap_content`, otherwise with `match_parent` it would fill the width of the parent. And since we have free space between the layout and the image, the `layout_gravity` attribute will center the `ImageView` inside the layout, which is the same size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="exitApplication"
            android:contentDescription="exit"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/exitbutton" >
        </ImageView>
  </LinearLayout>
```